# Calling a DLL from Go - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: go, dll

I'm trying to convert a program from Python (2.7, 32-bit) to Go (1.12.5, 32bit), and failing miserably with an access violation. The program calls a function in a 32-bit dll (ehlapi32.dll).

The following clips of the Python code appear to work perfectly (I'm not affirming that they are correct!):

```
class ehlapi32:
    hllDll       = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Personal Communications\EHLAPI32.dll"
    hllDll       = ctypes.WinDLL(hllDll)
    hllApiProto  = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_void_p,ctypes.c_void_p,
                                      ctypes.c_void_p,ctypes.c_void_p)
    hllApiParams = (1, "p1", 0), (1, "p2", 0), (1, "p3",0), (1, "p4",0),
    hllApi       = hllApiProto (("HLLAPI", hllDll), hllApiParams)
    pFunConnect  = ctypes.c_int(1)
...
    def connect(self):
        shlSession = self.session + b'\0\0\0'
        pText      = ctypes.c_char_p (shlSession)
        pLength    = ctypes.c_int (len(shlSession))
        pReturn    = ctypes.c_int (13)

        ehlapi32.hllApi (ctypes.byref (ehlapi32.pFunConnect), pText,
                         ctypes.byref (pLength), ctypes.byref (pReturn))
```

Now here's what I'm trying as the Go equivalent. This fails:

```
// ElFunc: EHLLAPI Functions
type ElFunc uint32

const (
    eConnect    ElFunc = 1  // Connect to a terminal
)
...
// Session: a 3270 session handle
type Session struct {
    SessId  string
    SysId   string
    Entry   string
    Result  []string
    Headers int
    Footers int
    Rows    int
    Cols    int
    Scroll  int
    Proc    *syscall.LazyProc
}
...
func (s Session) Connect() uint32 {
    // Load EHLLAPI DLL
    dll := syscall.NewLazyDLL(dllName)
    s.Proc = dll.NewProc(dllProc)
    // Connect to session
    rc := s.ecall(eConnect, s.SessId, 1, 0)
    if rc == 0 {
        defer s.Disconnect()
    }
...
// ecall: provides simplified EHLLAPI DLL calls

func (s Session) ecall(fun ElFunc, buffer string, count uint32, ps uint32) uint32 {
    rc := ps
    _, _, _ = s.Proc.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(uint32(fun)))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(count))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(rc))),
    )
    return rc
}
```

The failure looks like an access violation at `s.Proc.Call` in `ecall()`.

I realise that `syscall` is deprecated; I have also tried with `golang.org/x/sys/windows`, without success. I have no constraints as to which I use.

I'll confess I'm way out of my depth here.

Comment: When rc == 0 the defer activates. The point is, place defer before anything else because when you have an error, the connection stays open and will give strange results. Rebooting computer is the only option to close the connection.

Comment: @Dippo Are you referring specifically to EHLAPI Connect/Disconnect? Or something generic. The defer is to ensure that the session with PC3270 is closed; it doesn't make sense if the Connect hasn't been successful.

Comment: You must replace the defer with a Println. The defer must be the first line in the main procedure. So, when something goes wrong, the defer must kick in to remove everything what has to do with the dll connection. An example can be found here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

Comment: Also, i think something is wrong in the function ecall, rc is never overwritten once you call the dll.